# Application Insights - Cross Table Calculation Query

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, kql

I'm trying to summarize the count of exceptions, the count of requests, and then the ratio of exceptions / requests. I can't determine how to calculate the two summaries and then project the ratio and return it. I'm trying something along the following without success:

```
let exceptionCount = exceptions
| where type == "ShiftDigital.InventoryServices.API.GetVehicleException" and outerMessage !contains("Invalid zip code")
| count as ExceptionCount;

requests
| count as RequestCount
| extend RequestCount / exceptionCount
```

Can someone please advise on the correct way to structure this query?

Comment: Hi @James, please accept the answer below if it helps (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know how and why to do it). Thanks! (And if you're still missing info, please add a comment describing what's missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing [`toscalar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction)

```
let exceptionCount = toscalar(exceptions
| where type == "ShiftDigital.InventoryServices.API.GetVehicleException" and outerMessage !contains("Invalid zip code")
| count);
let requestsCount = toscalar(requests
| count);
print requestCount * 1.0 / exceptionCount
```